# Visual Studio 2008 does not show recent projects

Tags: visual-studio-2008, recent-documents, recent-file-list

I have installed Visual Studio in my laptop. Laptop is run by Windows XP SP3.
And Visual Studio 2008 (with SP1) does not show recent files in Start Up page. Buy the way VS 2008 does not show recent projects and files in File menu. Any suggestion?:)

UPD. In "Tools -> Options -> General-> Recent Files"  is all ok.

UPD. Buy the way Windows XP OS does not show recent files in Start menu.

Comment: These seem to contradict each other

UPD. In "Tools -> Options -> General-> Recent Files" is all ok.

Windows XP does not show recent files too

Comment: I have just edited on "UPD. Buy the way Windows XP OS does not show recent files in Start menu"

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General

Check that under 'Recent Files' there are some numbers entered?

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. Same figures as me - must be default value.

Have just looked through all settings under Tools -> Options and can't see anything else that relates to it.